# Use multiple GPUs on Pytorch

Tags: python, multiprocessing, gpu, torch

I have two GPUs, and both of them are CUDA devices, but I don't know, how to use both of them to train my resnext model:
[link](https://github.com/Helias/Car-Model-Recognition) for a github repository, which I took as a base code for my project. The only important thing I've changed is this:

```
    resnet152_model = resnet.resnext50_32x4d(pretrained=True)
    model = resnet152_model
    model = nn.DataParallel(model).to(device)
```

where my device is:

```
device = torch.device('cuda')
```

if I write cuda, it should use all available GPUs, but it is not. It uses my first GPU, and it will use only my second GPU if I write:

```
torch.cuda.set_device(1)
```

What is my mistake and how to make my code use multiple GPUs